# Installation of wsp with install-pnpsolution not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, pnp-powershell, project-server

We are developing a workflow solution for Project Server 2019. I am developing a script to automatically deploy the solution. The solution is in a local WSP-file. So far I have the following little script:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://server/sites/pwa001 -Credentials $cred
Install-PnPSolution -SourceFilePath C:\Dev\WorkflowDev\Workflows.wsp -PackageId $id
```

The script runs through fine without any errors, but the solution is not being installed on the server.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. In the end it was really simple. After the call to `Install-PnPSolution` I had to add an `Invoke-PnPQuery`. So the working script looks like:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://server/sites/pwa001 -Credentials $cred
Install-PnPSolution -SourceFilePath C:\Dev\WorkflowDev\Workflows.wsp -PackageId $id
Invoke-PnPQuery
```